# Meteor redirect client from server-side method

Tags: reactjs, meteor, paypal-subscriptions, react-router-dom

Meteor 1.6, React, React Router

Interfacing with Paypal billing-agreements

Client onClick event:

```
subPayPal(){
  Meteor.call('paypal.getToken', this.props.user_id, (error, response) => {
    if(error) { 
      console.warn(error);
    }else{
      console.log(response);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm calling the method on the server rather than on the client because I'm dealing with privileged info (usernames, passwords, tokens, etc). No problem here.

Server methods:

```
Meteor.methods({
   'paypal.getToken': function getOauthToken(uid){
      // simplified a bit
      // check if current token valid
      // set vars here, then go get token
      axios.post(ppAPI, data, config)
       .then( function(response) {
          // save oAuth token
       })
       .catch( function(error){
         // stuff here
       })

      // prepare another axios.post(), with oauth Token, to get a payment token 
      // and approval_url and execute_url from paypal

     // call axios.post() and use data in response:

     // with the approval_url in this reponse, I need to redirect
     // the browser to the approval_url on paypal.com so that the user
     // can sign into paypal, and ok the subscription agreement.

    // once user 'ok' in paypal, the browser comes back to my site,
    // where I render a 'cart' with a final 'ok, purchase' button.
    return approval_url;
   }
})
```

So, once I have the approval_url, I can send it back to the client, and when the client "sees" it, it can then call the React Router to the paypal.com site.

PROBLEM

The client's onClick method is obviously async and as soon as I click the initial `onClick()`, the console.log outputs `undefined` for `process` which makes perfect sense.

TRIAL 1

So, I tried using `Meteor.apply` in the client trying to make it synchronous, waiting for the server-side method to return the `approval_url` to no avail:

```
subPayPal(){
  Meteor.apply('paypal.getToken', [{uid:user_id}], {
    onResultReceived: (error, response) => {
      if(error) console.warn(error.reason);
      if(response) console.log('server response', response);
    }
  });
}
```

I also tried `Meteor.call('paypal.getToken').then({ console.log(response) }).catch...` to no avail either, as it is still async.

I've also tried try/catch blocks in the server-side method, to no avail. Whatever I try, the server-side code always runs as expected (with exception of the `Meteor.call().then().catch()` which just plain failed). I just can't seem to promise it, or return it.

TRIAL 2

The next thought would be not caring about the response on the client, if I could get the server-side method, with `approval_url` defined, to somehow call the React Router on the client and push the unique `approval_url` to it, but that doesn't make much sense to me how to wire that up.

THOUGHT 1

I guess I could use some "temporary" database collection, which is reactive, so that when the server-side method completes, it'll update (or insert/create) a document, and when the client 'sees' that, it could then call the React Router to redirect the browser to paypal.com. The collection document would have to hold the `approval_url` URI, which would then be passed down to the client. Not too sure how I'd wire the client to tell the Router when it sees the `approval_url` "appear".

Sooooo....

Any ideas? Is there more than one solution (and if so, what would be the best?).

I read somewhere that the app should logout the user, then the Router could redirect to paypal, but that doesn't help, as paypal.com redirects back to me, and I wouldn't want the user to have to log back in again.

THANKS.

Comment: You can return a promise from the method, and the server will return the result to the client when it is resolved. You can also use async/await. This is a fairly common issue and question.

Comment: @MasterAM can you elaborate? In my op in the client code I use `.apply()` which should make it wait. I also tried using promises in the form of `.call().then.catch()` as stated above to no avail.

Comment: I solved it. I'll post an answer shortly. Thanks to all for looking.